# C# Get Rows From DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to get all the rows in a DataGridView in a foreach function. How can I do this?

I.E. foreach() for each row, so for each row I could run code that would utilize the first and second column data.

This is in c#

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: So much better to access the DataSource the Grid is bound to.

Comment: It's not bound to one. Its supposed to be populated by the user.

Comment: I.E. I put a datagrid view in a windows Form and am letting the user create values and then get data from it.

Comment: Very rarely a good idea. A grid is a control to Present data, not a container to Store data. It can be done but that doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way of accessing this data is either through the `Data Source`:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = someData;
someData.property;
```

OR, if the user is entering data on the page, you can access from the `FindControl` method:

```
name = ((TextBox)dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("name")).Text;
```

In this case, if you've raised an event for a specific row, it will return `EventArgs e`, with a specific `RowIndex`. Then you can access the Column values via the `ControlID` within the column, such as `<asp:TextBox id="name" runat="server" />` from `.FindControl("name")`.

The important thing to remember is that you have to cast that object back to the type that it should be from the `.FindControl()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, it's always a good practice to bind the DataGridView to a data source, and then using the data source to do anything data-related. This keeps you clean from interacting with the datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{
     //Your code here
}
```

Comment: I know this. How can I get the data from Coloum 1 and Colum 2 from this? Strings.